# How can I automatically add new number when I click the "Add" button in PyQt5 PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, pycharm, sql-insert

We're doing a project where it requires to add number automatically in "Document No." field in PostgreSQL using PyCharm and QtDesigner (UI), but we failed to have an automatic document number instead, the last document number itself is what it shows when we click the add form for adding a data. Please help, thank you very much!

```
        cursor = connection.cursor()  # Table Widget with Database
        sql_select_loan_list = """  SELECT elid, eldocno eldate, elpostdate, elrefno, 
                                           eldesc, 
                                           eid, llid, 
                                           eltotal, elpaid, elamt, elpostamt, 
                                           elcancel, elfiler_amt, elfiler_by, elfiler_on, 
                                           elapprove_amt, elapprove_by, elapprove_on, 
                                           elcreatedby, elcreatedon, elupdatedby, elupdatedon
                                    FROM employee_loan 
                                    ORDER BY eldocno DESC """

        cursor.execute(sql_select_loan_list, )
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        row_number = + 1
        self.loanTable.insertRow(row_number)
        self.hreloaew.entryLoanDocNo.setText(self.entryLoanGetDocNo.text())
        row_number = + 1

        sql_count_query = """ SELECT count (*) FROM employee_loan """
        cursor.execute(sql_count_query, )
        row = self.loanTable.rowCount()
        connection.commit()
        row_number = + 1

        # insert into database and change to edit
        elid = self.hreloaew.entryLoanID.text()
        eldocno = self.hreloaew.entryLoanDocNo.text()

        self.entryLoanGetDocNo.setText(self.hreloaew.entryLoanDocNo.text())
        mydocno = + 1
        if mydocno == 0:
            if self.hreloaew.lblLoanAddEdit.text() == "Add Loan":
                mydocno += 1
                sql_insert_query = """   INSERT INTO employee_loan (
                                                                eldate, elpostdate, elrefno, 
                                                                 eldesc, 
                                                                 eid, llid, 
                                                                 eltotal, elpaid, elamt, elpostamt, 
                                                                 elcancel, elfiler_amt, elfiler_by, elfiler_on, 
                                                                 elapprove_amt, elapprove_by, elapprove_on, 
                                                                 elcreatedby, elcreatedon, elupdatedby, elupdatedon ) 
                                                    VALUES (     %s, %s, %s, 
                                                                 %s, 
                                                                 %s, %s, 
                                                                 %s, %s, %s, %s, 
                                                                 %s, %s, %s, %s, 
                                                                 %s, %s, %s, 
                                                                 %s, %s, %s, %s )  """

                insert_user_input = (eldate.toPyDate(), elpostdate.toPyDate(), elrefno,
                                     eldesc,
                                     eeid, lllid,
                                     eltotal, elpaid, elamt, elpostamt,
                                     elcancel, elfiler_amt, elfiler_by, elfiler_on,
                                     elapprove_amt, elapprove_by, elapprove_on,
                                     elcreatedby, elcreatedon, elupdatedby, elupdatedon,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

```
sql_select_query = """                      SELECT elid, eldocno, eldate, 
elpostdate, elrefno, 
                                           eldesc, 
                                           eid, llid, 
                                           eltotal, elpaid, elamt, elpostamt, 
                                           elcancel, elfiler_amt, elfiler_by, elfiler_on, 
                                           elapprove_amt, elapprove_by, elapprove_on, 
                                           elcreatedby, elcreatedon, elupdatedby, elupdatedon
                                    FROM employee_loan 
                                    ORDER BY eldocno DESC
                                    LIMIT 1 """
        print(1)
        cursor.execute(sql_select_query, )
        record = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in record:
            myid = row[0] + 1
            mydocno = row[1] + 1

            self.hreloaew.entryLoanID.setText(str(myid))
            self.hreloaew.entryLoanDocNo.setText(str(mydocno))
```